# Ajax async post not working

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have the following code, works perfectly, except that it hangs my page for 5+ minutes when I run it.

For some reason I can not get it to run async and continue on the script. It just stops and will not echo the "success!" until it has completely finished. What am I doing wrong.

```
<script>
    $( ".sendit" ).click(function( event ) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var subject = $('#subject').val();
        var message = $('#message').val();
        var userid = '<?php echo $userid;?>';

        $.ajax({
            async: true,
            url: 'send.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: {subject, message, userid},
            success:function(data){
                var form = document.getElementById("myForm");
                form.reset();
                alert("Success!");
                location.reload();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: The `success` callback of an AJAX function won't be fired until it has completed. Also, AJAX is asynchronous by default; In fact, it's what the A in AJAX stands for - there is no need to specify it. If you want things to run before the AJAX has finished, you should put them before or after the AJAX call, not inside of it.

Comment: @Santi that makes it so the alert and reload happen instantly, but that doesn't prevent the site from hanging until I clear SESSION cookies. Thats the problem I am trying to sort. The process still carries out, but I have to completely clear my session cookies and log back into the site to stop the site from continuously loading.

Comment: Async is the default, you don't need to do anything special to make it run async.

Comment: There's nothing in the code you posted that will cause the page to hang. Put `alert("Sent!")` after the AJAX call and you should see that immediately.

Comment: Are there any errors in the Javascript console?

Comment: When I submit with ajax that should pass the data as POST to my form. As this happens in the background the form itself shouldn't cause my account to hang (short of hanging the entire server). However this is not whats happening. When I send this data to the form the form runs a loop submitting emails to all members. If I limit the sending to 1 member no hanging, If I submit it to many thousands, it hangs MY ACCOUNT not the server and requires I clear sessions. My understanding is ajax should hand off in the background and short of a server load my browser and sessions should not be affected?

Comment: there are no errors at all in javascript console or php logs. It just hands until the entire form is processed - sometimes timing out with a 500 error.

Comment: add error handling in .ajax call